# How can I let my users upload multiple pictures at the same time?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a ruby on rails website. One feature allows people to upload pictures but users find it painstaking to upload pictures one at a time. What is the best way to allows users to upload multiple pictures at the same time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try Uploadify or SWF upload. I've used both on Codeigniter projects but I prefer Uploadify. Both are flash based, have similar interfaces and are easily configurable. They allow multiple uploads in a queue and users can cancel the uploads too.

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Multiple file fields or some javascript magic to do multiple file fields

I'm not a big fan of those javascript/flash uploaders, but they might be to your liking.

Answer (score 0):

It's not problem to have two fields in your form for two different file attributes on an object.  if you are using the paperclip plugin, you would just have two attachments in the model.

You may have a one-many situation where you want to allow the user to click "add file" or "remove file" in a dynamic way to expose more fields.  If so, check out Ryan Bates site at railscasts.com - the last few episodes are about hierarchical forms.